A proposition about concave functions
If the function $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb{R}$ is a concave function on the interval $(a, b) $, it is not difficult to prove that:
$$
\forall x_{2}>x_{1},x_{1},x_{2}\in (a,b),\frac{1}{x_{2}-x_{1}}\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \geq \frac{\max _{x\in[x_{1},x_{2}]}\{ f(x) \}+\min _{x\in[x_{1},x_{2}]}\{ f(x) \}}{2}
$$
So is the inverse proposition of this proposition correct? That is, if $f \in C (a, b) $ and satisfies
$$
\forall x_{2}>x_{1}, x_{1},x_{2}\in (a,b),\frac{1}{x_{2}-x_{1}}\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \geq \frac{\max _{x\in[x_{1},x_{2}]}\{ f(x) \}+\min _{x\in[x_{1},x_{2}]}\{ f(x) \}}{2}
$$
Is $f $ necessarily a concave function? If not, what about assuming $f \in C ^ 2 (a, b) $?
